# streamlit API key hidden from deployed app

Tags: user-interface, security, streamlit, api-key

I have created a Streamlit app that grabs some data using a private API key and then does some wrangling and outputs a CSV file. The data grab uses an API key that needs to be hidden from the final user of the app. I am wondering whether this is possible, as when you deploy the app locally to be run from the cmd line, the user will have access to the repo. Alternatively, if you deploy the app on Heroku or something similar it seems that you have to include the API key in a TOML file using Secrets Management:
https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/connect-to-data-sources/secrets-management

Is there a way of deploying the app to the end user without them having access to the API key?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the link you had on secrets management. The user cannot access the key if you host it in streamlit cloud for example.

Answer (score 1):

Store the API key as config vars on heroku (from the dashboard go to Settings --> Reveal Config Vars). Then in your python code you can access them using `os.environ["<key>"]` instead of using `st.secrets["<key>"]`.